# T-SQL: Conditional NULL removal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, isnull

I need to select only the `Room_IDs` that have no instances where the `Status` is  NULL.

For example here :

TABLE_A

```
  Room_Id   Status    Inspection_Date
  -----------------------------------
    1        NULL        5/15/2015
    2        occupied    5/21/2015
    2        NULL        1/19/2016
    1        occupied   12/16/2015
    4        NULL        3/25/2016
    3        vacant      8/27/2015
    1        vacant      4/17/2016
    3        vacant     12/12/2015
    3        vacant      3/22/2016
    4        vacant       2/2/2015
    4        vacant      3/24/2015
```

My result should look like this:

```
  Room_Id  Status  Inspection_Date
  -----------------------------------
    3       vacant      8/27/2015
    3       vacant     12/12/2015
    3       vacant      3/22/2016
```

Because `Room_ID` '3' has no instances where the `Status` is NULL

Comment: You do not need for TSQL to do this. Just write a simple query using `NOT EXIST` with correlated subquery.

Comment: @PM77-1 TSQL is a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example of how to do it:

```sql
DECLARE @tTable TABLE(
Room_Id INT,
Status VARCHAR(20),
Inspection_Date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @tTable VALUES 
 (1, NULL, '5/15/2015'),
 (1,NULL,        '5/15/2015'),
 (2,'occupied',  '5/21/2015'),
 (2,NULL,        '1/19/2016'),
 (1,'occupied',  '12/16/2015'),
 (4,NULL,        '3/25/2016'),
 (3,'vacant',    '8/27/2015'),
 (1,'vacant',    '4/17/2016'),
 (3,'vacant',    '12/12/2015'),
 (3,'vacant',    '3/22/2016'),
 (4,'vacant',    '2/2/2015'),
 (4,'vacant',    '3/24/2015')

 SELECT * FROM @tTable T1
  WHERE Room_Id NOT IN (SELECT Room_ID FROM @tTable WHERE Status IS NULL)
```

Gives :

```
Room_Id |   Status |    Inspection_Date         |
-------------------------------------------------
3       |   vacant |    2015-08-27 00:00:00.000
3       |   vacant |    2015-12-12 00:00:00.000
3       |   vacant |    2016-03-22 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Table1 
 WHERE Room_ID NOT IN 
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT Room_ID
   FROM Table1
   WHERE Status IS NULL
   )
```

The sub query returns a list of unique room id's that, at one time or another, had a NULL status.  The outer query looks at that list, and says "Return * where the room_ID IS NOT one those in the subquery.

If you want to try it in SQL Fiddle, here is the Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (Room_ID int, Status varchar(8), Inspection_Date datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (Room_ID, Status, Inspection_Date)
VALUES
    (1, NULL, '2015-05-15 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'occupied', '2015-05-21 00:00:00'),
    (2, NULL, '2016-01-19 00:00:00'),
    (1, 'occupied', '2015-12-16 00:00:00'),
    (4, NULL, '2016-03-25 00:00:00'),
    (4, 'vacant', '2015-08-27 00:00:00'),
    (1, 'vacant', '2016-04-17 00:00:00'),
    (3, 'vacant', '2015-12-12 00:00:00'),
    (3, 'vacant', '2016-03-22 00:00:00'),
    (4, 'vacant', '2015-02-02 00:00:00'),
    (4, 'vacant', '2015-03-24 00:00:00'),
    (2, NULL, '2015-05-22 00:00:00')
;
```

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to Hashman, I just prefer to use `not exists` over `not in` for these types of queries.

**Creating some test data**

Note that I just kept the same date for everything since it's not imperative to the question.

```
create table #table_a (
    Room_Id int,
    Status varchar(32),
    Inspection_Date date);

insert #table_a (Room_Id, Status, Inspection_Date)
    values
        (1, null, getdate()),
        (2, 'occupied', getdate()),
        (2, null, getdate()),
        (1, 'occupied', getdate()),
        (4, null, getdate()),
        (3, 'vacant', getdate()),
        (1, 'vacant', getdate()),
        (3, 'vacant', getdate()),
        (3, 'vacant', getdate()),
        (4, 'vacant', getdate()),
        (4, 'vacant', getdate());
```

**The query**

```
select *
from #table_a t1
where not exists (
    select *
    from #table_a t2
    where t1.Room_Id = t2.Room_Id
        and Status is null);
```

**The results**

```
Room_Id     Status                           Inspection_Date
----------- -------------------------------- ---------------
3           vacant                           2016-06-17
3           vacant                           2016-06-17
3           vacant                           2016-06-17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE and NOT EXIST like below code

```
WITH    bt
      AS ( SELECT   RoomId ,
                    Status,
                    Inspection_Date
           FROM     dbo.Table_1
         )
SELECT  *
FROM    bt AS a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   bt
                     WHERE  bt.RoomId = a.RoomId
                            AND bt.Status IS NULL );
```

Comment: There is no need in CTE here.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev
take it easy, This is just one of the solutions

Comment: But it is one solution where the CTE does nothing.  It is exactly the table.  You can just refer to the table.